# does this make difference on performance to run 'setContentView' in thread or not?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, setcontentview

does this make difference on performance to run 'setContentView' 
in thread or not ????

```
ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
     } });
```

Comment: in which thread ? Btw, `setContentView(R.layout.main);` has always to be called from the main thread (aka UI thread)

Comment: As @Blackbelt says, UI changes must be always done on UI Thread. Taht code won't make any performance upgrade.

Comment: @Gonzalo if it has no performance  upgrade , how should i initialize my views in another thread to boost up performance ??

Comment: @MH480 As I told you in the other comment and as Blackbelt told you, UI can only be modified in UI Thread, tehre is no "other thread" where you can change views, it will give you an error if you try, you could benefit from read ``AsyncTask`` documentation.